# JPA/Hibernate Initialize object after a many-to-many join with another join

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

Sorry for the poorly worded title, but I had no idea how to actually phrase it.

I currently have 3 tables (I'm not sure how to format tables on SO):

```
FOO
---------
ID
NAME
^^^^^^^^^
BAR
---------
ID
NAME
^^^^^^^^^
FOO_BAR
---------
ID
ID_FOO
ID_BAR
SOME_STRING
```

What I'm currently doing is joining FOO and BAR based on the ID_FOO and ID_BAR from the FOO_BAR table, which works. I get a nice List inside each Foo object.

What I'm now trying to do (at least understand how to) is to also populate a list inside each Bar object with the FOO_BAR.SOME_STRING columns. To give you an example:

FOO_BAR contains:

```
ID_FOO | ID_BAR | SOME_STRING
1      | 1      | a
1      | 1      | b
1      | 2      | a
2      | 1      | c
```

What I would like to end up with in my Foo object is the following:

myFoo contains a list of two (2) Bar objects with ID 1 and 2. Each Bar object will have a list of strings (in this case) initialized with the FOO_BAR.SOME_STRING values. So barList[0] would be a list of {"a", "b"} and barList[1] would be a list of just the string "a".

Is there any way I can do this in a simple(-ish) way? Again, sorry for the weird title.

Edit: I added an extra entry in the FOO_BAR table to show the following situation. foo(1) will have 2 Bar objects, the first one bar(1) having 2 strings in its list. Object foo(2), however, also has bar(1) in its list, but bar(1) will have just string "c" in its list.

Answer (score 0):

Based your question, your `FOO_BAR` table wouldn't necessarily be structured that way.  If we model this out in JPA you effectively have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class Foo {
  // only including attributes that are of interest here, others omitted
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
  List<Bar> barList;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BAR")
public class Bar {
  // only including attributes that are of interest here, others omitted
  @ManyToMany
  private List<Foo> foo;
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "FOO_BAR_STRINGS")
  private Set<FooString> someStrings;
}

@Embeddable 
public class FooString {
  @ManyToOne
  private Foo foo;
  private String stringValue;
}
```

This should lead to a schema that has tables named `FOO`, `BAR`, `FOO_BAR`, and `FOO_BAR_STRINGS`.

The `FOO` and `BAR` tables will hold only the basic attributes you store as a part of their respective entities.

The `FOO_BAR` table will maintain a cross-reference for the `@ManyToMany` association between `Foo` and `Bar`, something akin to:

```
 +--------+---------
 | foo_id | bar_id |
 +--------+--------+
 |      1 | 1      |
 |      1 | 2      |
 +--------+--------+
```

Lastly, there will be a `FOO_BAR_STRINGS` collection table that will have three columns, the identifier of the associated `Foo` and `stringValue` associated with the owning `Bar` object.  A combination of all 3 values are represented by the embeddable component called `FooString`.

Here's a visual example:

```
 +--------+--------+-------------+
 | bar_id | foo_id | stringValue |
 +--------+--------+-------------+
 |      1 |      1 | a           |
 |      1 |      1 | b           |
 |      2 |      1 | a           |
 |      1 |      2 | c           |
 +--------+--------+-------------+
```

This gives you a completely normalized view of your data based on your mappings.

There are a variety of ways `FooString` and its table structure could be realized; this being only one way.  Another way would be to instead apply the element-collection on the `Foo` object and change `FooString` to be `BarString` where it holds a reference to a specific `Bar`.

Comment: I added an extra example now. The pk of the third table should be the pair of foo_id and bar_id, because you can have foo(1) contain bar(1) with a list of two strings, but the bar(1) could also be part of foo(2), but have only one string (which could be different from the first two). Is this too weird to design using joins? Maybe I should just have the list as comma-separated strings and just have one field which I'll then turn into a list in code?

Comment: If you need both `Foo` and `Bar` to be associated with a given string, you could always change the element-collection to hold an embeddable that maps the `Foo` , `Bar`, and string-value as an entry.   I'll update my example with that.